# Have unrooted Samsung Galaxy 10.2 Tablet. I want to delete files, wondering if I can do it with USB cable then use Explorer to maintain files?

Tags: insufficient-memory, storage, maintenance

Have an unrooted tablet, a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.2. Memory is getting tight on the tablet itself and my card is 64GB with most still available. I saw the answer using `logcat` built-in utility to delete log files and such. I would rather do it myself due to having routines that have done what they weren't supposed to do. I like having full control over what happens, let's just say I'm an old DOS fan who likes to do the nitty-gritty.